# ItextSharp With multiple signature not locking set fields

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

Hi guys new to this i m kinda stuck and would love your insight on the matter. I am able to sign a pdf form from itextsharp. 
The digital signature falls in place but the fields that i have set to lock in adobe if a signature occurs are not getting locked.Even Though it works directly i.e. if i go put the signature in adobe instead of using (itextsharp) the fields get locked . I am using the code very similar to [Lockfields on gitlab](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itextsharp/tutorial/blob/1fabe4976601d4d85a29cb126e6dc4cf1c384607/signatures/chapter2/C2_12_LockFields/C2_12_LockFields.cs)
only difference is i am using an already existing pdf with the rules set for which fields to lock when the pdf is signed.So the problem is in my pdf there are too many fields to lock one by one using **itext** sharp i'd rather raise an event or something in adobe sayin the signature has fallen and put rules that i have set to active.

Comment: Please share the PDF in question

Comment: you can take any pdf form put a signature field and assign the locking rules and test it